# Dealing with unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transition

Tags: ios, mkmapview, segue, viewcontroller

I am using mapView with an callout from a simple annotation. I used the below delegate method

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)_mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

    lbhProfileMapPoint *mp = (lbhProfileMapPoint *) view.annotation;
    NSLog(@"mp objectID: %@", mp.objectID);
    self.objectId = mp.objectID;
    [[lbhVariables sharedInstance] setMapViewChosenObjectId:self.objectId];

    //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"profileSegue" sender:self];
    lbhProfileViewController *pvc = [[lbhProfileViewController alloc] init];
    [pvc setObjectId:self.objectId];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pvc animated:NO];
}
```

It doesn't go to the viewcontroller but keeps saying

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <lbhProfileViewController: 0x1f017ec0>.
```

actually the lbhProfileViewController, It's connected within my storyboard via other viewcontrollers. But with this accessory callout, I want to manually call it. As you can see I have

```
//[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"profileSegue" sender:self];
```

in the code, but if I use this method instead, it still gives me unbalanced calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method you should also use `prepareForSegue:sender:` method. Your code in `prepareForSegue:sender:` method will be something like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryBoardSegue*) segue sender:(id) sender
{
     if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"profileSegue"]){
         lbhProfileViewController *pvc = [segue destinationViewController];
         [[segue destinationViewController]setObject:sender.objectId];
     }
}
```

Also to use this, you will need a segue directly connecting to the `lbhProfileViewController` from the view controller calling the map delegate method.

Comment: The segue should just be wired straight from the VC to the lbhProfileViewController right? I don't know how to wire from the callout button to the destinationController

Comment: oh! and also profileViewController has two ContainerViews ...FYI

Comment: It does not matter if the profileViewController has two container views. If you have the storyboard enabled, you will need to wire a segue from your viewController with the mapView to the profileViewController. This can be done by right clicking on the viewController in the storyboard and dragging a connection to the profileViewController. Also, don't forget to name the segue you create.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

in the ViewDidDisappear method, I was doing a self.navigationController pop method, so it clashed with this.

But yes this helps thanks!